# How can I connect android cordova contacts plugin to blackberry 10 app?

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry-10

I added org.apache.cordova.contacts plugin to android cordova project. After that, I repackage  android .apk file to .bar file for BlackBerry 10. Contacts plugin doesn't work, it doesn't add contact to my book contacts.

During debug I noticed that contact is saved, id contact is returned, but JSONObject  by this id return null.

```
if (action.equals("save")) {
            final JSONObject contact = args.getJSONObject(0);
            this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject res = null;
                    String id = contactAccessor.save(contact);
                    if (id != null) {
                        try {
                            res = contactAccessor.getContactById(id);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "JSON fail.", e);
                        }
                    }
                    if (res != null) {
                        callbackContext.success(res);
                    } else {
                        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, UNKNOWN_ERROR));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I connect android contacts plugin for blackberry?